# Running out of heap running Proguard in Android Gradle build

Tags: build, gradle, obfuscation, proguard, heap-memory

When I try to run Proguard on my local machine from within my Gradle build, I get a "Java heap space" error. Specifically:

```
:<app_name>:proguardRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':<app_name>:proguardRelease'.
> Java heap space
```

I tried setting my GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx2048m, but I'm still getting the heap space error.

Any suggestions?

Here's the end of my log output:

```
:Tinder:proguardRelease
ProGuard, version 4.9
Reading input...
Reading program directory [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/classes/release]
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/library.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/libs/androidannotations-api-2.7.1.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/libs/picasso-1.1.1.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/libs/gcm.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/ViewPagerIndicator.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/nineoldandroids.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/libs/crittercism_v3_0_11_sdkonly.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/libs/google-play-services.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/facebook.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/PullToRefresh.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Applications/android-studio.app/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/13.0.0/support-v4-13.0.0.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/libs/apphance-library.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/simple-crop-image-lib.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/windowed-seek-bar.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/libs/com.kontagent.android.sdk.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/ActionBarSherlock.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/google-play-services_lib.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/libs/gson-2.2.4.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/jabdulius/Documents/Dropbox/workspace-tinder/Tinder/build/exploded-bundles/volley.aar/classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading library jar [/Applications/android-studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar]
:Tinder:proguardRelease FAILED
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you also export the environment variable (on Linux and BSD)?

```
export GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. My build got that error at task `shrinkReleaseMultiDexComponents`.

Answer (score 3):

If someone runs into this problem within AndroidStudio, without Gradle, the solution is to add some memory to proguard :

```
Android Studio >> Preferences >> Compilers >> 
Android Compiler >> Proguard Options = -Xmx2048m
```